# How to change dimensions of metafile figure output in Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, metafile

I have a client who would like to use Rmarkdown to make figures into a Word Document and then edit them (I know... not really the point of reproducible research, but it's what the client wants...)

````
 ----
 title: "MinReproEx_Metafile" 
 author: "Erika Mudrak" 
 date: "Thursday, July 17, 2014" 
 output: word_document
 ----

 Try to put a bigger metafile figure in a work document 

 ```{r, echo=FALSE, dev='win.metafile', fig.height=6, fig.width=6}
 plot(cars) 
 ```
````

---

Using `dev='win.metafile'` places the figure as an editable metafile, but regardless of the input for `fig.height` and `fig.width` the figure is 1.67 x 1.67 inches. So somehow the `dev='win.metafile'` overrides these chunk options.

The knitr option page has this about `dev.args`:

> dev.args: (NULL) more arguments to be passed to the device, e.g.
>   dev.args=list(bg='yellow', pointsize=10); note this depends on the
>   specific device (**see the device documentation**); when dev has multiple
>   elements, dev.args can be a list of lists of arguments with each list
>   of arguments to be passed to each single device, e.g. <>=

Where can I find the device documentation for the metafile format to which this refers?

Comment: The documentation is in `?windows` but you'll only have than on a windows build IIRC. You don't need to use a metafile to dump into a word document. It should be fine with PNG, TIFF, or EPS as well - unless you mean they physically want to edit the metafiles in place. Then, errr, Yuck.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this](http://gforge.se/2014/07/fast-track-publishing-using-rmarkdown/) recent posting by Max Gordon on RMarkdown. He mentions `out.width` etc there and discusses a new package that adds capabilities such as `force_captions` that might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try `out.height=6, out.width=6`. (try different numbers) 
If still does not work, just tell them copy the figures from the `figure/` file folder (usually in the same directory as your Rproj) and then paste in their doc files. `Knitr` saves all figures in your computer if `cache=TRUE`.

Comment: As the document is in markdown and that markup "language" has no concept of figure widths and heights `out.width` and `out.height` get converted to raw HTML in the rendered `md` document (as you go from `Rmd` to `md`). What Pandoc then does with such input when rendering to a `doc[x]` file is another question altogether.